# Forcing bound UI components to refresh

Tags: c#, wpf

I know this has been asked a few times but none of the answers work for me.

I've got this list of elements in a TreeView which when clicked show their parameters in a panel (with texboxes, labels, combos and other components). I also have a button that allows copying data from one element chosen in a combo to the one currently shown on the data panel ("copy data from...").

All the data in the panel is bound to a class and its properties, and the treeview is bound to a collection of those objects.

The problem is, when I press the copy button (i.e. copying data from object A to current object) the changes are not reflected. Yet, if I change the element to be displayed (clicking another object in the TreeView) then go back to the changed object, the changes are there. So it is in fact changing the actual data, but not refreshing de data bindings.

Strangely enough, If I press the Copy button twice, changes are indeed reflected.

Which may be the cause of this, and how would I solve it?

This is the XAML example of a control that should be updated (I only post one because there are lots, and none of them is working), the copy button and the treeview:

Copiar datos del protocolo:
                                
                                
                                    
                                        
                                        Copiar

```
<TreeView SelectedItemChanged="TvProtocolosSelectedItemChanged" Margin="10,5" Name="tvProtocolos" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="200" Height="292" MinWidth="0">
                    <TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
                        <Style TargetType="TreeViewItem">
                            <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="{Binding Path=Activo}"/>
                            <Setter Property="IsExpanded" Value="False"/>
                        </Style>
                    </TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
                    <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
                        <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Children}">
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <Image Source="imagenes\file_icon.gif" Margin="0,0,5,0" />
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}" ></TextBlock>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
                    </TreeView.ItemTemplate>

                </TreeView>
```

And this is the code-behind file:

```
public partial class NewXP2 : Window
    {
        private const int nProtocolos = 100;
        private Experiencia2 _exp2Class = new Experiencia2(nProtocolos);
        private readonly TreeView _tvProtocolos;


        public NewXP2()
        {
InitializeComponent();
_tvProtocolos.ItemsSource = _expClass.Protocolos;
xpControlsPanel.DataContext = _exp2Class.GetProtocolo(0);
            for(int i=0;i<nProtocolos;i++)
                copyFromCombo.Items.Add("Protocolo " + (i+1));
            copyFromCombo.SelectedIndex = 0;
}

        private void CopyfromButtonClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            int protIndex = copyFromCombo.SelectedIndex;

            int indiceProtocolo = 0;
            if (_tvProtocolos == null)
                return;

            var g = _tvProtocolos.SelectedItem as Composite;

            _listaData = GetData();
            _tvProtocolos.ItemsSource = _listaData;
            TreeViewItem tvi;
            if (g != null)
            {
                tvi = _tvProtocolos.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(g.Indice) as TreeViewItem;

                if (tvi != null)
                {
                    tvi.IsSelected = true;
                }
                indiceProtocolo = g.Indice;
            }

            _exp2Class.SetProtocolo(indiceProtocolo, _exp2Class.Protocolos[protIndex]);

        }
```

And this is the class bound to the panel (with the textbox)

```
public class ProtocoloExp2: ISerializable, IDataErrorInfo
    {
 public ProtocoloExp2(int idx)
        {
            IndiceProtocolo = idx;
            IndiceVisual = idx + 1;
        }
        public float TimeToShowTarget { get; set; }

        (...)
}
```

Comment: Sounds like something's broken in your INotifyPropertyChanged implementation, but without a relevant code sample it's hard to tell.

Comment: What exaclty should I post? I'm not using that interface in any of my classes. I think I might be losing something here...

Comment: Post the smallest possible repro of the issue.

Comment: Posted some code, tried to make it short by limiting it to one control. (None of them work anyway)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check ["How to: Implement the INotifyPropertyChanged Interface"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229614.aspx) out. And consider using [ObservableCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604.aspx) for your lists. Implementation of INotifyPropertyChanged interface is a requirement for wpf controls view models it basically allows views to refresh themselves when data changes.

Comment: I will check that out, although my bindings worked perfectly so far, in both directions.

Comment: Not if you change property form code after it is displayed say on "copy data from..." button click.